# Specifying SELECT, then joining with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just hit a wall with my SQL query fetching data from my MS SQL Server.

To simplify, say i have one table for sales, and one table for customers. They each have a corresponding userId which i can use to join the tables.

I wish to first `SELECT` from the sales table where say price is equal to 10, and then join it on the userId, in order to get access to the name and address etc. from the customer table.

In which order should i structure the query? Do i need some sort of subquery or what do i do?

I have tried something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sales
WHERE price = 10
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Sales.userId = Customers.userId;
```

Needless to say this is very simplified and not my database schema, yet it explains my problem simply. 
Any suggestions ? I am at a loss here.

Comment: You just need to know the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SELECT` has a certain order of its components

In the simple form this is:

- What do I select: column list
- From where: table name and joined tables
- Are there filters: WHERE
- How to sort: ORDER BY

So: most likely it was enough to change your statement to

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sales
INNER JOIN Customers ON Sales.userId = Customers.userId
WHERE price = 10;
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what i needed. I will remember that guideline.
Thanks for the explanation.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause must follow the joins:

```
SELECT * FROM Sales
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Sales.userId = Customers.userId
WHERE price = 10
```

This is simply the way SQL syntax works. You seem to be trying to put the clauses in the order that you think they should be applied, but SQL is a declarative languages, not a procedural one - you are defining what you want to occur, not how it will be done.

You could also write the same thing like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE price = 10
) AS filteredSales
INNER JOIN Customers
ON filteredSales.userId = Customers.userId
```

This may seem like it indicates a different order for the operations to occur, but it is logically identical to the first query, and in either case, the database engine may determine to do the join and filtering operations in either order, as long as the result is identical.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fine to me, did you run the query and check?

```
SELECT s.*, c.*
FROM Sales s

INNER JOIN Customers c 
ON s.userId = c.userId;

WHERE s.price = 10
```